# Help with the line 誰かと似ていて放っておいても行ってしまいそうだからね

Tags: grammar, translation

Context: There has been an incident and law enforcement is scrambling anyone and everyone to go after the wrongdoers. Our protagonist is getting ready to set off, when person B (who was earlier taken into custody for being related to the incident and because they were heavily injured) comes and begs to come with the MC to the scene. MC wants to refuse because the person was heavily injured recently but the person claims and seems to have recovered.

This is when the Chief calls in and says the following. The bolded line is the problematic one:

> 僕の権限で許可は出してる同行してくれ
>
> On my authority I’m granting you permission. Go together.
>
> **誰かと似ていて放っておいても行ってしまいそうだからね**
>
> ?????????
>
> 作戦に組み込んだ方が安心できるんだ
>
> With her included in the operation I’ll be able to have peace of mind.

From the context and some of the verbs in the problematic sentence, I'd guess that the Chief is castigating the MC for leaving behind someone who could help. But I can't for the life of me figure out how does the sentence work. If I take my time and segment it, it comes out as kinda jiberish:

> 誰かと似ていて

Someone looking alike/possessing the shape - I guess this might be "Someone capable as you" or something if we stretch the meaning of 似{に}る "Possessing the nature and state/condition nearly the same"

> 誰かと似ていて放っておいて

"There is someone similar in condition and is being left behind" with も it would become "Even if you leave behind someone of similar capability".

The other side of the sentence:

> 行ってしまいそうだからね

"(I'm granting permission) because (you) unfortunately seem to be leaving"

So I can grok these two sides on their own. But together:

"You seem to be going in spite of there being someone similar you and are leaving them behind"

This allmost makes sense now, but why put ても on 放っておく? As far as I know ても indicates some sort of conflict with the rest of the sentence (Even if it's A someone is doing B and like). But leaving someone as is (behind) isn't really in conflict with going. It would have been less weird for me if ても was on 似ていて.

Sooo yeah. Can someone break down this sentence for me and explain it's meaning and where did I get lost here?

I hope this is enough context, coz there isn't really that much more relevant to the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

似る doesn't just mean similar in shape. It also means similar in circumstances or disposition. Here, the Chief is saying that the main character is similar in disposition/temperament to someone else.

放っておいても means even if the main character were left behind. The て-form + も means even if.

行ってしまいそう doesn't mean that the character seems to be leaving. It means that the main character seems likely to leave (on his own).

All together the Chief is saying to the main character:

> I'm letting you go because like someone else, even you were left behind, you would likely go on your own.

Comment: You flipped them about, but yeah, I can see this working. Thanks.

Comment: From this answer, I cannot tell if the answerer is familiar with the 'special' usage of 誰か.  It is not used to mean  the plain "someone" here.

Comment: @l'électeur Are you trying to say that it refers to a certain someone else the chief knows (and is thinking of)?

Comment: Context wise it's I take it to reffer to the MC, coz the MC is the type of person who would charge into danger regardless. And so he is saying: "I'm letting you, person B, go because like certain someone (the MC) if you were left here, you are likely to follow regardless". Unless there is some other meaning? @l'électeur